# Warning: require_once(/home/content/28/11459128/html/system/startup.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: php, stream, warnings

I have recently taken backup for my website and wanted to open with xampp on local host but it is showing following errors:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/content/28/11459128/html/system/startup.php): failed to open 
stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\index.php on line 26

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
'/home/content/28/11459128/html/system/startup.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\index.php on line 26
```

Can any one help me with this issue.

Thanks,

GC

Comment: It could not open the file. Make sure you are opening the file at its exact location and check if the file exists

Comment: error shows you line no change path to local dir

Comment: Hi I have changed the path and now it is showing following error: Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\haya\vqmod\vqmod.php on line 329


Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\haya\vqmod\vqmod.php on line 329
Kindly see to it and let me know the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to change all the PATH in your project according to your local machine**, or there must a variable in your config file i.e Path to project for local environment is `C:/xampp/htdocs` and for production server it must be `/home/content/whatever`. If it is not present you better create one.

I am pretty sure path won't start with `/` on Windows(local machine).

Comment: Hi I have changed the path and now it is showing following error: Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\haya\vqmod\vqmod.php on line 329 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\haya\vqmod\vqmod.php on line 329                                  Kindly see to it and let me know the best possible solution.

Comment: It's a warning, but the code should work. Like it says switch to preg_replace_callback function as it would be in no use in future php version and your code might stop working. If you want to suppress the error put @ before the function preg_replace, but that's not at all recommended, always fix the code. :)